# After I install ng bootstrap and compile, I get this error

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.d.ts:191:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 191     set ngbPanelToggle(panel: NgbPanel);
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/checkbox.d.ts:28:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 28     set focused(isFocused: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:14:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 14     get disabled(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:15:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 15     set disabled(isDisabled: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:61:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 61     set value(value: any);
>              ~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:65:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 65     set disabled(isDisabled: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:66:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 66     set focused(isFocused: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:67:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 67     get checked(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:68:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 68     get disabled(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:69:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 69     get value(): any;
>              ~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts:70:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 70     get nameAttr(): string;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.d.ts:42:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 42     set interval(value: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.d.ts:43:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 43     get interval(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.d.ts:47:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 47     set wrap(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.d.ts:48:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 48     get wrap(): boolean;
>              ~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.d.ts[0m:58:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 58     set pauseOnHover(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel/carousel.d.ts:59:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 59     get pauseOnHover(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-service.d.ts:16:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 16     get model$(): Observable;
>              ~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-service.d.ts:17:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 17     get dateSelect$(): Observable;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts:234:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 234     get state(): NgbDatepickerState;
>               ~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts:240:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 240     get calendar(): NgbCalendar;
>               ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts:200:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 200     get disabled(): any;
>               ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts:201:9
>   - errorm TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 201     set disabled(value: any);
>               ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-month.d.ts:26:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 26     set month(month: NgbDateStruct);
>              ~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.d.ts:15:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 15     set disabled(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.d.ts:16:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 16     get disabled(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-ref.d.ts:40:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 40     get componentInstance(): any;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/nav/nav.d.ts:64:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 64     get active(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/nav/nav.d.ts:65:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 65     get id(): any;
>              ~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/nav/nav.d.ts:66:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 66     get panelDomId(): string;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/progressbar/progressbar.d.ts:12:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 12     set max(max: number);
>              ~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/progressbar/progressbar.d.ts:13:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 13     get max(): number;
>              ~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tabset/tabset.d.ts:91:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 91     set justify(className: 'start' | 'center' | 'end' | 'fill' |
>   'justified');
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:35:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 35     set hourStep(step: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:36:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 36     get hourStep(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:40:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 40     set minuteStep(step: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:41:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 41     get minuteStep(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:45:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 45     set secondStep(step: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:46:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 46     get secondStep(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:72:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 72     get isSmallSize(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/timepicker.d.ts:73:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 73     get isLargeSize(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts:100:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 100     set ngbTooltip(value: string | TemplateRef);
>               ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts:101:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 101     get ngbTooltip(): string | TemplateRef;

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: try upgrading TypeScript to latest version

Answer (score 39):

Replace `@ng-bootstrap / ng-bootstrap` in `package.json` with this :

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~5.2.2"
```

and do `npm i`

this worked fine for me.

Comment: Yup. This work for me after downgrading ng-bootstrap version.

Comment: Fixed for me also. The docs say ng-bootstrap 6 is for Angular 9 (I'm on 8). I assumed it would be backwards compatible - guess not :)

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: I had installed Angular 7 so i had to replace like this:
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1". Compatibility table is in this page: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: Hey, you are really great, It made my job simple and it worked for me. Hail you. I tried for the solution for two days. Great. - Rammohan

Answer (score 8):

Short Answer ***(if you are running Angular 8)***:
In your project, run the following command on the cli: 
`npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.0`

Long Answer:
Please check the version of your angular project and make sure you install the NgBootstrap version that is compatible with your angular project.

Take a look at the dependencies:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

You can check the version of angular using the cli: `ng version` or you check your package.json file.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when trying to install ng-bootstrap at first, perhaps my troubleshooting can give you some insight.

I resolved this issue by updating angular and the CLI using:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Then installed the bootstrap package via NPM (just in case you skipped it during the installation)

```
npm install bootstrap
```

afterwards I installed ng-bootstrap

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

after all this the app launched, but it was blank! so i checked the console and there was a message saying i had to add localize with the following command:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

After these steps I had my angular app up and running, hope this helps.

EDIT: also don't forget to include the reference to *node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css* in your *angular.json* file

Comment: the same problem still persists.

Comment: could you share your angular, bootstrap and ng-bootstrap versions? or a repo of you project perhaps

Comment: Yes, this works for me. ng update  is needed to update angular to version 9+. ng add @angular/localize is needed if you are using ng-bootstrap >= v6 and angular > v9.

Comment: Although i ended up using angular/material, the installation process was similar since I forgot to commit or stash the angular update.

Comment: Upgrading angular version wo 9+ will help for me. Ngbootstrap 6+ needs angular version 9+

Answer (score 5):

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.2"
```

Replace @ ng-bootstrap / ng-bootstrap in package.json with the section above. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue:**

> ERROR in node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.d.ts:191:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.** and so on.....

**Solution**

> Change @ng-bootstrap / ng-bootstrap  in package.json with this
>   dependencies :

```
   "dependencies": {

    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~5.2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

For my Angular 8 app, I used this dependency version:
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~5.3.0"

Using 5.2.2 as mentioned previously, didn't work for me. Some tag attributes like **cardClass** (Ex: `<ngb-panel [disabled]="disabled" [cardClass] ...>`) are supported starting from 5.3.0.

You have also to execute the command `npm i` as mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just downgrade the ng-bootstrap package

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also same issue to be solved by

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this in two ways.

way 1:

step-1 Open `angular.json` file and downgrade the ng-bootstarp version as follow

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~5.2.2"
```

step-2 run `npm i`

Way 2:

run `ng add @angular/localize`

either of the ways will fix your issue.